# Getting error message "Server port In Use 8080-Http" when running servlet on jetty

Tags: java, jetty, port

Trying to run a servlet with jetty and I'm getting the error message "Server port In Use 8080-Http". I assume we can just change the port, but I have no clue how.

Comment: two server r running on same port 8080.Change the port no for one of the server

Comment: How do I change this? Is this something I do in eclipse, or do I have to edit a .xml?

Comment: mvn -D jetty.port=9999 jetty:run

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port via the command line, jetty.port=8081.

Comment: Duplicate issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652058/how-to-override-jetty-xml-with-jetty-port