# Change Jetty default port

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Jetty default port is 8080, but I want to change to default port to some other port (9999).

I read a few tutorials and they said almost all of configuration information is by default maintained in file `jetty.xml`, this file is located under `$JETTY_HOME/etc/`. Then, change property `jetty.port` to 9999. However, when I opened up that file, I couldn't find jetty.port property inside the `jetty.xml`. I'm currently using Jetty-9.2.1 and the port is at 8080.

I found jetty.port property under jetty-http.xml file. Even though I changed the port to 8090 in the jetty-http.xml file, jetty is still running at port 8080.

**jetty.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Documentation of this file format can be found at:              -->
<!-- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_syntax        -->
<!--                                                                 -->
<!-- Additional configuration files are available in $JETTY_HOME/etc -->
<!-- and can be mixed in. See start.ini file for the default         -->
<!-- configuration files.                                            -->
<!--                                                                 -->
<!-- For a description of the configuration mechanism, see the       -->
<!-- output of:                                                      -->
<!--   java -jar start.jar -?                                        -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Configure a Jetty Server instance with an ID "Server"           -->
<!-- Other configuration files may also configure the "Server"       -->
<!-- ID, in which case they are adding configuration to the same     -->
<!-- instance.  If other configuration have a different ID, they     -->
<!-- will create and configure another instance of Jetty.            -->
<!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.server.Server for all              -->
<!-- configuration that may be set here.                             -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Configure the Server Thread Pool.                           -->
    <!-- The server holds a common thread pool which is used by      -->
    <!-- default as the executor used by all connectors and servlet  -->
    <!-- dispatches.                                                 -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- Configuring a fixed thread pool is vital to controlling the -->
    <!-- maximal memory footprint of the server and is a key tuning  -->
    <!-- parameter for tuning.  In an application that rarely blocks -->
    <!-- then maximal threads may be close to the number of 5*CPUs.  -->
    <!-- In an application that frequently blocks, then maximal      -->
    <!-- threads should be set as high as possible given the memory  -->
    <!-- available.                                                  -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool   -->
    <!-- for all configuration that may be set here.                 -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- uncomment to change type of threadpool
    <Arg name="threadpool"><New id="threadpool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool"/></Arg>
    -->
    <Get name="ThreadPool">
      <Set name="minThreads" type="int"><Property name="threads.min" default="10"/></Set>
      <Set name="maxThreads" type="int"><Property name="threads.max" default="200"/></Set>
      <Set name="idleTimeout" type="int"><Property name="threads.timeout" default="60000"/></Set>
      <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
    </Get>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Add shared Scheduler instance                               -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler"/>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Http Configuration.                                         -->
    <!-- This is a common configuration instance used by all         -->
    <!-- connectors that can carry HTTP semantics (HTTP, HTTPS, SPDY)-->
    <!-- It configures the non wire protocol aspects of the HTTP     -->
    <!-- semantic.                                                   -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- This configuration is only defined here and is used by      -->
    <!-- reference from the jetty-http.xml, jetty-https.xml and      -->
    <!-- jetty-spdy.xml configuration files which instantiate the    -->
    <!-- connectors.                                                 -->
    <!--                                                             -->
    <!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.server.HttpConfiguration       -->
    <!-- for all configuration that may be set here.                 -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
      <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
      <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
      <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
      <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.send.server.version" default="true" /></Set>
      <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
      <Set name="headerCacheSize">512</Set>
      <!-- Uncomment to enable handling of X-Forwarded- style headers
      <Call name="addCustomizer">
        <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
      </Call>
      -->
    </New>


    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set the default handler structure for the Server            -->
    <!-- A handler collection is used to pass received requests to   -->
    <!-- both the ContextHandlerCollection, which selects the next   -->
    <!-- handler by context path and virtual host, and the           -->
    <!-- DefaultHandler, which handles any requests not handled by   -->
    <!-- the context handlers.                                       -->
    <!-- Other handlers may be added to the "Handlers" collection,   -->
    <!-- for example the jetty-requestlog.xml file adds the          -->
    <!-- RequestLogHandler after the default handler                 -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
         <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
           <Item>
             <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
           </Item>
         </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- extra server options                                        -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
    <Set name="stopTimeout">5000</Set>
    <Set name="dumpAfterStart"><Property name="jetty.dump.start" default="false"/></Set>
    <Set name="dumpBeforeStop"><Property name="jetty.dump.stop" default="false"/></Set>

</Configure>
```

**jetty-http.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<!-- ============================================================= -->
<!-- Configure the Jetty Server instance with an ID "Server"       -->
<!-- by adding a HTTP connector.                                   -->
<!-- This configuration must be used in conjunction with jetty.xml -->
<!-- ============================================================= -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add a HTTP Connector.                                       -->
  <!-- Configure an o.e.j.server.ServerConnector with a single     -->
  <!-- HttpConnectionFactory instance using the common httpConfig  -->
  <!-- instance defined in jetty.xml                               -->
  <!--                                                             -->
  <!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.server.ServerConnector and     -->
  <!-- o.e.j.server.HttpConnectionFactory for all configuration    -->
  <!-- that may be set here.                                       -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8090" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="http.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

</Configure>
```

I was also advised to use an integration test to configure Jetty to use other port. There's a `integration-tests.properties` file inside the project. Maybe a solution is to set jetty.port to 9999 inside this file?

**integration-tests.properties:**

```
host = localhost
port = 9999
```

Comment: Changing the jetty.port setting inside jetty-http.xml worked for me. Maybe you have another application using port 9999?

Comment: For changing ssl default port: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72082416

Answer (score 35):

does it work if you set the port when you start it from the command line like this:

```
java -jar start.jar -Djetty.port=9999
```

Comment: This doesn't change the default port. After running this line, Jetty still runs under port 8080 when I run `java -jar start.jar`. I'm looking for a way to permanently change the default port.

Comment: @wag0325 I was just wondering if it would make a difference in order to troubleshoot the issue. After I updated jetty/start.d/http.ini and changed the port to 9999 and then run the default settings: java -jar start.jar it starts up on port 9999. If you need to run it from maven then this post may help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652058/how-to-override-jetty-xml-with-jetty-port)

Comment: The documentation said.. `mvn -Djetty.http.port=8181 jetty:run` but your suggestion works for me. May be because I have context path defined like this `      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
        <configuration>
          <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/http</contextPath>
          </webAppConfig>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
`

Comment: `mvn -Djetty.port=8181 jetty:run` helps you start jetty on port 8181

Comment: BTW if using spring boot with jetty underneath you should use `--server.port=8090`

Answer (score 11):

I did this in Jetty 9.x version. 
You need to go to `$JETTY_HOME/start.ini` file and edit this setting     **jetty.port**.

Lets say that you want to run jetty at 9090 port: 
Please change `jetty.port` setting in `$JETTY_HOME/start.ini` from

```
jetty.port=8080
```

to

```
 jetty.port=9090
```

Then start jetty using `java -jar start.jar` option.
Then jetty will be running at 9090 port than default 8080 port.
Then do `curl -i -XGET "http://localhost:9090"`. That should give you 200 http status.

Thats it.

Answer (score 10):

Update:

On Jetty 9.x, `jetty.port` has been deprecated and you can use `jetty.http.port` instead, as shown below:

```
$> cd $JETTY_HOME && java -jar start.jar -Djetty.http.port=8080
```

Answer (score 7):

On jetty 9.2.3.v20140905 it`s need to write in `/etc/default/jetty`

```
# JETTY_ARGS
#   The default arguments to pass to jetty.
#   For example
JETTY_ARGS="jetty.port=8080 jetty.spdy.port=8443 jetty.secure.port=443"
```

but this change only http port. To change https port in jetty 9.2 create ini file `$JETTY_HOME/start.d/https.ini`

```
# Initialize module https
#
--module=https
## HTTPS Configuration
# HTTP port to listen on
https.port=8443
# HTTPS idle timeout in milliseconds
https.timeout=30000
# HTTPS Socket.soLingerTime in seconds. (-1 to disable)
# https.soLingerTime=-1
```

jetty [9.3](http://fossies.org/linux/www/jetty-distribution-9.3.10.v20160621.tar.gz/jetty-distribution-9.3.10.v20160621/bin/jetty.sh) in `/etc/default/jetty`

```
# JETTY_ARGS
# The default arguments to pass to jetty.
# For example
JETTY_ARGS="jetty.http.port=8080 jetty.ssl.port=443"
```

or command line parameters `-Djetty.http.port=8080 -Djetty.ssl.port=443`

Answer (score 4):

I changed the port successfully, you can try to edit `jetty.port` in the file located at `$Jetty_home/start.d/http.ini`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the http port in the start.ini file because it will over-right jetty-http.xml config.Or just comment the line in start.ini and keep your config from jetty-http.xml.
In [jetty home]/start.ini

```
## HTTP port to listen on
#jetty.port=8080
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness on jetty 7 you can use this:

```
java -jar start.jar --module=http jetty.port=9080
```

Comment: That's a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **eclipse** you need to set the run configurations. When you install **jetty** in eclipse, the default port for jetty is **8080**.

So you need to change it into an XML file. If the problem remains, you need to change it in eclipse run configurations.

I hope it works, as it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ, this can be done similar to Magnus Lassi's command-line answer.

Run --> Edit Configurations --> Add "-Djetty.port=XXXX", e.g.:

```
jetty:run-war -Djetty.port=9999
```

Answer (score 0):

For SSL port you can pass the param:

```
-Dssl.port=8445
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a spring boot application, inside your application.properties file
add
`server.port = preferred port number eg. 8082`

[IMAGE OF PORT CONFIGURATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMiyM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `jetty.http.port` property in `jetty/start.ini` and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For changing `SSL` port, you need to change `jetty.ssl.port` property in below directory:

- `$JETTY_HOME/etc`

  - `jetty-ssl.xml`

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
...
  <Call  name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
      ...
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.ssl.port" deprecated="ssl.port" default="8443" /></Set>
      ...
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
...
</Configure>
```