# Using Jetty 9 and jetty.xml with BaseX

Tags: ssl, webserver, jetty

In Jetty 8, it was fairly easy to overwrite the standard server port and add an SSL connector in a custom `jetty.xml` file as follows:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="port">8984</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8986</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="Port">8986</Set>
        <!-- keystore, password, keyPassword, ... -->
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

As this configuration is not accepted by Jetty 9 anymore, I have checked out the [Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html) and related StackOverflow issues (like [How to override jetty.xml with jetty.port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652058/how-to-override-jetty-xml-with-jetty-port)) without success.

How can the configuration be rewritten to do the same in Jetty 9?

Comment: On jetty9, basex http server works for me using jetty.xml : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/apb2006/b24e92f84c42838ec7ef7de2cf937835/raw/65cf6ddb74e3e2cda17cc6883866c85e438a5c3b/jetty.xml refers to this as well:
https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/pipermail/basex-talk/2018-March/012977.html

Comment: Yes, we found a solution that works pretty well (and we forgot to share this here).

Answer (score 1):

There is little to no reason to be editing XML files anymore with Jetty 9.

Use the Jetty 9 module system and `${jetty.base}` concepts.

```
$ cd /opt/jetty
$ tar -zxvf jetty-distribution-9.3.3.v20150827.tar.gz
$ mkdir my.base
$ cd my.base
$ java -jar ../jetty-distribution-9.3.3.v20150827/start.jar \
  --add-to-start=http,https,deploy,webapp
INFO: server          initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: http            initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: ssl             initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: https           initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: webapp          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: deploy          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
DOWNLOAD: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/plain/jetty-server/src/test/config/etc/keystore?id=master to ${jetty.base}/etc/keystore
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/webapps
INFO: Base directory was modified
$ ls -laF$ ls -laF
total 48
drwxrwxr-x.  4 joakim joakim  4096 Sep 23 06:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 22 joakim joakim 12288 Sep 23 06:00 ../
drwxrwxr-x.  2 joakim joakim  4096 Sep 23 06:01 etc/
-rw-rw-r--.  1 joakim joakim  5009 Sep 23 06:01 start.ini
drwxrwxr-x.  2 joakim joakim  4096 Sep 23 06:01 webapps/
```

At this point:

- Replace the `etc/keystore` file with your SSL keystore.
- Edit the start.ini for:

  - your http port (`jetty.http.port`)
  - your https port (`jetty.https.port`)
  - and your various SslContext / keystore values (see keys starting with `jetty.sslContext.`)

When complete, run Jetty ..

```
$ cd /opt/jetty/my.base
$ java -jar ../jetty-distribution-9.3.3.v20150827/start.jar
2015-09-23 06:05:40.619:INFO::main: Logging initialized @272ms
2015-09-23 06:05:40.764:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.3.v20150827
2015-09-23 06:05:40.779:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/my.base/webapps/] at interval 1
2015-09-23 06:05:40.790:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1718d616{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-09-23 06:05:40.810:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509=X509@7e0babb1(jetty,h=[jetty.eclipse.org],w=[]) for SslContextFactory@6debcae2(file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/my.base/etc/keystore,file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/my.base/etc/keystore)
2015-09-23 06:05:40.810:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509=X509@5ba23b66(mykey,h=[],w=[]) for SslContextFactory@6debcae2(file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/my.base/etc/keystore,file:///home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/my.base/etc/keystore)
2015-09-23 06:05:41.026:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@305fd85d{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2015-09-23 06:05:41.027:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @680ms
```

Curious what your server configuration looks like?  Run this...

```
$ cd /opt/jetty/my.base
$ java -jar ../jetty-distribution-9.3.3.v20150827/start.jar --list-config
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! We are configuring and starting Jetty from another software (see https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-api/src/main/java/org/basex/BaseXHTTP.java), and we are using a self-contained [jetty.xml](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-api/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty.xml) file to configure Jetty-specific settings. I am wondering if we can maintain a similar setting with Jetty 9?

Comment: Here is some (basic) [user documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Web_Application) on how we use jetty.xml.

Comment: Not without some serious code updates from BaseXdb (eg: it makes assumptions about the connectors and connector architecture that are not valid).   There's no such thing as a SelectChannelConnector in Jetty 9+, as its moved on with the needs of the modern world (TLS/ALPN) and the updates that HTTP/2 bring to the table.  The old SelectChannelConnector concept was insufficient to accomplish this.